# loading the arrays that are stored in the plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, plist

I have a plist that holds in each dictionary info for a node.
Every node has a longitude, a latitude and connections to other nodes.
Here is a small piece of the plist.

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>connections</key>
        <array>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <integer>3792</integer>
        </array>
        <key>latitude</key>
        <real>45.43876</real>
        <key>longitude</key>
        <real>12.3213</real>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>connections</key>
        <array>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <integer>3793</integer>
        </array>
        <key>latitude</key>
        <real>45.43887</real>
        <key>longitude</key>
        <real>12.32122</real>
    </dict>
```

Also I have class called IGNode to store the info, see here the .m implementation.
I assume the header isn't needed to show here.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface IGNode : NSObject

@property double lon;
@property double lat;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *links;


@end
```

So far I have the loading of the latitude and the longitude to work.
However I have no clue on how to get the connections array out of the plist.
I looked at a lot of examples on stackoverflow but I can't translate them to what i have to do.

This is what I have so far.

```
for (int i=0; i<plistData.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *nodeDict = plistData[i];

    IGNode *node = [self.nodes objectAtIndex:i];

    node.lon = [[nodeDict valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
    node.lat = [[nodeDict valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];

    // handle connections
    // ?

}
```

How can i get store the connections array in the node.links?

Comment: Side note - You should be using `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:` to get the values from the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this....

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Configs" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *tmpDicts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

You can then enumerate the array of tmpDicts and extract the connections array from each one.

```
IGNode *node;
for (NSDictionary *dict in tmpDicts)
{
    node = [[IGNode alloc]init];
    node.lon = [[dict valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
    node.lat = [[dict valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    node.links = [[dict valueForKey:@"connections"]mutableCopy];

    // Do something with the node (like add it to an array?)
}
```

Comment: thanks.
The connections array has indexes. How can i loop them?
I want something like: `        for(NSInteger *indexLink in links) {
            [node.links addObject:[links objectAtIndex:*indexLink]];
        }`

Comment: To be a bit more clear, in node.links i want to store references to other nodes, not integers.

Comment: You'll have to loop through the connections array rather than mutablecopying it and use the intValue of each entry as an index into your links array and then add those objects to a new mutable array that you create as `node.links` - Sorry, but I' not going to write your program for you! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (NSDictionary *nodeDict in plistData) {

    IGNode *node = [self.nodes objectAtIndex:i];

    node.lon   = [nodeDict[@"longitude"] doubleValue];
    node.lat   = [nodeDict[@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    node.links = [nodeDict[@"connections"] mutableCopy];

}
```